# Register command for StatusBarItem

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, statusbaritem

I am creating a Visual Studio Code extension and have read that in order to provide a functionality to the StatusBarItem onclick event I need to [register a command for the status bar item](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/11279). How do I do this? When I create a StatusBarItem using window.createStatusBarItem I get an object which doesn't seem to have any string as identifier but the command registering process requires a string as first argument and I am not sure how to associate it with the StatusBarItem.

I have used yeoman to bootstrap a JavaScript extension.

**extension.js**

```
const vscode = require('vscode');
const { exec } = require('child_process')

function activate(context) {
    console.log('Thanks for installing me! Remember to add a script to run if you want this extension to do anything \
    instersting at all :P');

    // TODO: make status bar item clickable
    const statusBarItem = vscode.window.createStatusBarItem(vscode.StatusBarAlignment.Right, 1000);

    function runCommandAndUpdateStatusBarItem () {
        // TODO: fetch command from settings
        const command = 'git describe --dirty="-$USER"';
        exec(`cd ${vscode.workspace.rootPath} && ${command}`, [], (error, stdout, stderr) => {
            if (stdout) {
                statusBarItem.text = `$(git-commit) ${stdout}`;
                statusBarItem.show();
            }
            else {
                vscode.window.showErrorMessage(stderr);
                statusBarItem.hide();
            }
        });
    }

    statusBarItem.hide();

    let disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand('extension.sayHello', runCommandAndUpdateStatusBarItem);

    context.subscriptions.push(statusBarItem);
    context.subscriptions.push(disposable);
}
exports.activate = activate;

function deactivate() {
    console.log('Oh...so, you hate me? Ok I go away now :(');
}
exports.deactivate = deactivate;
```

**package.json**

```
{
    "name": "script-result-info",
    "displayName": "Script Result Info",
    "description": "Runs a script in shell and puts the result in the statusBar",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "publisher": "emilioidk",
    "engines": {
        "vscode": "^1.23.0"
    },
    "categories": [
        "Other"
    ],
    "activationEvents": [
        "onCommand:extension.sayHello"
    ],
    "main": "./extension",
    "contributes": {
        "commands": [
            {
                "command": "extension.sayHello",
                "title": "Hello world"
            }
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "postinstall": "node ./node_modules/vscode/bin/install",
        "test": "node ./node_modules/vscode/bin/test"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "typescript": "^2.6.1",
        "vscode": "^1.1.6",
        "eslint": "^4.11.0",
        "@types/node": "^7.0.43",
        "@types/mocha": "^2.2.42"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When I create a StatusBarItem using window.createStatusBarItem I get an object which doesn't seem to have any string as identifier

It does not by default since it's optional, yes, but you can set `command` on it:

```
statusBarItem.command = 'extension.sayHello';
```

Check the API docs for `StatusBarItem`: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#StatusBarItem

Comment: I feel so silly! I misread the documentation and thought that it was immutable. Thank you very much.

Comment: That's actually not that silly, the API docs are actually missing that info. :) Some of `StatusBarItem`'s properties such as `alignment` are in fact declared `readonly`:  https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/2362ec665c84a1519162b50c36ed4f29d1e20f62/src/vs/vscode.d.ts#L4115

Comment: You might prefer to use the API docs of the Haxe externs for the VSCode API, as they actually do include that information: http://vshaxe.github.io/vscode-extern/vscode/StatusBarItem.html